# JMS/Active MQ - broker vs consumer redelivery

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, message-queue

As I understand (http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html) a redelivery can be done by either a consumer or a broker. 
I have some questions though:

How does the redelivery by a consumer work underneath? Does the consumer cache the message from a broker and redeliver it locally? What does happen if a consumer terminates inbetween? Such message will be lost? I think that as long as the consumer does not acknowledge the message it shouldn't be. But in such case, the message will be still available on the broker?

Are there any guidelines when to use broker vs consumer redelivery? Any recommendations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The consumer does cache and redeliver the message to the client locally, until the redelivery count is met, then automatically acks the message as bad (posin ack). A consumer can control if it gets marked as redelivered depending on the acknowledgment mode.  If for whatever reason a consumer can't or does not want to process a message, it can also kick it back and it will be available for consumption again if it closes the session.

The broker will hold onto the message until it gets an ack from the consumer. If your consumer is set to AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE then it is possible you could lose the message if an unhandled exception occurs or the consumer ends unexpectedly for example.

Otherwise, if your consumer is using transactions or CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE it will give you the control on when that occurs.

With transactions, if the consumer drops prior to a commit it will be available for the next consumer or whenever that consumer reconnects.

I've always used transaction over CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE so I don't want to say for sure that the message will be lost in if the Session.recover() is not called before the consumer goes down or not.

From a consumer stand point, this is also known as retry logic.

Regarding broker vs consumer redelivery:  By default, the broker just keeps giving the consumer the same message until the redelivery count is met.  If you tell the broker not to redeliver it after a given amount of time, then your consumer can work on consuming other messages that may be able to be processed.

When to do this is really up to what is going on in your application.  Maybe a specific message needs to be put to a database and that database is not available at the moment and you want to move on to messages that go elsewhere/have another purpose?

Comment: This is not entirely correct.  The ActiveMQ MessageConsumer does hold a cache of message that have been delivered in a transaction and will redeliver them locally up to the set redelivery limit on TX rollback.

Comment: @TimBish thanks for the callout.  I thought had already edited this.  I started the response thinking about something else.

Comment: Does it mean that if we choose broker redelivery then the message won't be cached on the consumer and each time coming from the broker (thus increasing the network usage)? Another question: is there something like acknowledgement timeout, so that either broker or consumer will redeliver the message after some time without an ACK?

Comment: When using broker redelivery it should not be cached at that point as the messages is able to be re-dispatched to any other consumer right away (if configured to do so).

Comment: In most cases redelivery is a seldom event, but yes, technically it would increase network usage. There is no acknowledgement timeout.  The broker will have the message marked as dispatched to that consumer until the consumer's session goes away or generates the ack, so the client code will need to determine if something is taking to long to process.  You can have connection timeouts however

Comment: For some reason, I think using Redelivery Policy results in message loss which may happen at the broker. Every time, a message is consumed and I log the JMS header value JMSXDeliveryCount. Let's say there are 10,000 messages to be redelivered 5 times with an interval of 5 minutes, what I found was that, the first time I got all 10k, 2nd time 9995, 3rd time 9995, 4th time 9990, 5th time 9987. Sometimes all the time, I get 10k too. I believe Redelivery Policy uses the broker scheduler to store them and it may be buggy or uses a different mechanism to store scheduled messages resulting in loss.